# Problem on Bayes's Theorem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

It is given that there are total S players.
But the team consists of only N players.
 Messi and his group consists of M players (including Messi). Messi will be happy if there are at least K other players in the team from his group.

Find the probability that Messi will be happy given that he is selected in the team.

Comment: Zero: Messi just hates having to play silly games.

Comment: I'd say $1$, Someone just bought him a beer

Comment: Yeah, don't mess with Messi.

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: @AmitTiwari  We're being a bit silly :)  Can you tell us what you've tried and why you're having trouble with this question.  Try and translate it into proper mathematical language, then nobody can make stupid comments and you might find it easier to answer.

Comment: Is this related to codechef?

Answer (score 1):

We are told that Messi is on the team.  The rest of the team can be chosen in $\binom{S-1}{N-1}$ ways. We are invited to assume that all these ways are equally likely.

We want to count the number of ways in which the team has $i$ members from Messi's group, not including Messi. These $i$ members can be chosen in $\binom{M-1}{i}$ ways, and the rest of the $N-1-i$ members of the team can be chosen in $\binom{S-M}{N-1-i}$ ways. So the probability the team has $i$ additional members from Messi's group is
$$\frac{\binom{M-1}{i}\binom{S-M}{N-1-i}}{\binom{S-1}{N-1}}$$
ways. Add up, $i=K$ to $M-1$.

**Remark:** If for example the number of members in $M$ is greater than $N$, then some of the terms in the sum will involve binomial coefficients $\binom{a}{b}$, where $a\lt b$. That is no problem, if under such conditions we **define** $\binom{a}{b}$ to be $0$.

Comment: I removed my last comment in case you interpreted it as a criticism.  What I meant was that you could have said "This answer is somewhat Messi". I'm going to stop for tonight because I'm obviously in a silly mood.

Comment: No problem! I removed the beginning because I noticed that the comments already had enough plays on the word.

Comment: thanks.. I thought it to be a question of Bayes's Theorem..

Comment: We could use a conditional probability argument. Let $M$ be the event Messi is on the team, let $A$ be the event the team has at least $K$ of M's group. We want $\Pr(A|M)$, which is $\Pr(A\cap M)/\Pr(M)$. The calculation of $\Pr(A\cap M)$ is very similar to the one done above. It amounts to the same thing, just somewhat more complicated looking than what we did.