# Error in probability calculation

Tags: probability

I am facing some problem in below probability question

```
Bob's school is organizing a fire-camp to take students of her class to camp. There are S students in Bobs class.But School is planning to take only N out of these S to camp. These students will be picked up randomly

Bob's friend circle has M students including her. Though she is excited about the camp, she will enjoy it only if there are atleast K of her friends with her on the trip. What is probability that bob enjoys??..Assume that she is going for trip
```

The General formula I came out with is :

((M-1)C(k) * (S-1-k)C(N-1-k)) / (S-1)C(N-1)

This formula seems correct in most cases but I found 1 cases where it is not giving expected result:  Consider S=10 N=10 M=5 k=3

In above scenario answer should be 1.But as per my formula I am getting 4..

Can you tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: The same problem (different words) was [asked and answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380575/problem-on-bayess-theorem) today.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - Thanks. But I am not satisfied by the formula he proposed..Can you please tell me where am i wrong?

Comment: If you go to answer I referred to, you will see that it gives $1$. Do read the note about $\binom{a}{b}=0$ when $a\lt b$. In your example, the only $i$ for which $\binom{S-M}{N-1-i}\ne 0$ is $i=4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She is happy if atleast $k$ friends of hers go for the trip.

So, possible cases are: No. of her friends going for the trip$= k,k+1,k+2,...,M-1$

For first case, No. of arrangements, $N_k= {M-1\choose k}{S-M\choose N-k-1} $

For second case, No. of arrangements, $N_{k+1}= {M-1\choose k+1}{S-M\choose N-k-2} $

and so on...

For the last case, No. of arrangements, $N_{M-1}= {M-1\choose M-1}{S-M\choose N-M} $

Total arrangements possible without constraint(her being happy), $ T ={S-1\choose N-1}$

So required probability $=\frac{N_k+N_{k+1}+\cdots+N_{M-1}}{T}$

Comment: What if I do it like this : There are N seats available. We divide this N seats into two parts. First part will be occupied by Bobs friends.So selecting K seats out of N. Options : (M-1)C(K). Now students left S-1-K and seats left N-1-k.

Comment: Here you are fixing the number of her friends going for the trip; atleast $k$ must go implies more than $k$ can also go.

Comment: I am not fixing no. of friends as for first I am selecting exactly k but later in (S-1-k)C(N-1-k) I am considering students other than those k selected (This includes students who are Bobs friend and not selected in previous part too)

Comment: You multiply cases when they occur together. If you first fixed the num. of friends to $k$ in ${M-1\choose k}$ part, then you can't take any num. of friends case in second part $S-k-1\choose N-k-1$